# Importing project android

Tags: android, eclipse, import, github

I am following this guide to import a project from github: [Github](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537)

For some reason after importing the file as an android project it doesn't include source files or the manifest? What could be wrong?

Im using the newest Eclipse (ISR1)

Comment: Which of the two ways (referenced in your link) are you importing the project?  With or without Maven?  The instructions without Maven worked for me.  Can you give some more details?

Comment: Yeh without maven. What directories did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the pc and eclipse and worked after that, still don't know why..!